# Question about headline "Inmate Dies Anyway"

Tags: headline-english

I came across this headline: "Oklahoma Stops Botched Execution. **Inmate Dies Anyway**." ([link](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/publiccatholic/2014/04/oklahoma-stops-botched-execution-inmate-dies-anyway/))

I was truly disturbed by the use of "anyway".  To me, it implies a nonchalant attitude about something that is highly sensitive and controversial.  Am I wrong?  Is the use of "anyway" acceptable?

**Update:**

What made me post this question is the use of "anyway" in casual speech. For example, after a pause, one side says "Anyway, should we go to lunch?" So, I have this feeling about "anyway" being a less-than-worthy word that one would not use in formal settings. Am I still wrong?

Comment: You have a point, but then again this is but a blog. Not exactly the highest register.

Comment: It is a bit curt, but check the other headlines by the same blog author...She might be known for an irreverent or nonchalant style

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Here's a similar headline from a TV news channel: `Okla. execution: 'Chaos' after injection is stopped, inmate dies anyway`, from: http://www.whas11.com/news/Oklahoma-inmate-dies-after-execution-is-botched-257263351.html

Comment: The casual nature in "Anyway, should we go to lunch?" derives from the catch-all dismissal of anything that might have been previously under discussion. If the lunch in question is of great consequence (perhaps because of who you're meeting for lunch) and the previous topic or activity was very frivolous, it wouldn't appear casual at all. It would be a reminder that it's time to get down to business.

Comment: @frances +1 GREAT explanation, thank you so much.  You are right, frivolous activity, followed by "anyway", then followed by something serious, negates, in that context, the dismissive meaning of anyway.  BTW, I could not come up w/ the precision in the wording of your explanation even if someone held a gun to my head! :-)

Comment: Do you have an alternative? Is "nonetheless" better? "Still" is a bit ambiguous ("Inmate dies still" or "Inmate dies twitching"?). It's also a bit misleading to call it a headline; blog posts have titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyway can mean 'nonetheless', or it can mean 'whatever'.  You are hearing the usage like 'Whatever... let's move on', when the author meant 'Nonetheless... inspite of our efforts'

Comment: +1 That's it, "hearing" a certain usage was what was tripping me up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see much nonchalance in this case.

**Anyway** just means that something happens, notwithstanding actions that were expected to prevent it from happening.

> His father forbade him to do that, but he did it anyway.
>   The road was almost impossible to drive on, but we tried it anyway.
>   Because of the storm, we attached extra lines, but the tent flew away anyway.

Comment: Yes, but the use of "anyway" makes it seem as if the inmate had a choice.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Consider the synonym 'nonetheless'.  "I fixed the leg and the table fell over anyway." does not make for a sentient table.

Comment: @JonJayObermark - I understand, but can "fall" be used for a table?  A table is inanimate, and cannot fall on its own volition.

Comment: @Sabuncu: yes, in English, tables, rocks, trees can all fall. Falling is not considered to be a sentient action.

Comment: I fixed the leg and the table fell/collapsed/spontaneously combusted anyway