# Should I add "anyway" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> She looked at herself in the mirror and wondered if she should wear
>   makeup. She decided not to. What was the point if she'd remove it in a
>   couple of hours, (anyway)?

I'm a little confused. It sounds OK with and without the *anyway* to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a style (or perhaps meaning) issue, I think, not a grammar issue, regarding use of *anyway* at the end of the sample sentence.

I find either “What was the point if she'd remove it in a couple of hours, anyway?” or “What was the point if she'd just remove it in a couple of hours?” stylistically and semantically  preferable to “What was the point if she'd remove it in a couple of hours?”, a form that falls flat.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167305/question-about-headline-inmate-dies-anyway) on SE.

In the context of sentences like these, "Anyway" is defined as-

> Anyway just means that something happens, notwithstanding actions that
>   were expected to prevent it from happening.

And some examples, similar to your sentence-

> His father forbade him to do that, but he did it anyway.
>
> The road was almost impossible to drive on, but we tried it anyway.
>
> Because of the storm, we attached extra lines, but the tent flew away
>   anyway.

And last, as the previous answer says, the usage of "anyway" adds the semantic flair that is needed for this sentence. Other than that, it also emphasizes on the justification of the action where she decided not to wear her makeup -

> She decided not to